# external link subgurim google maps open infowindow

Tags: infowindow, subgurim-maps

this code is not working

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            InitializeServerSide();
            ConfigureClientSide();
        }
    }

```
private void InitializeServerSide()
{
    GLatLng latlng = new GLatLng(39, -0.5);

    GMarker marker = new GMarker(latlng);

    GMap1.Add(marker);
    InitializeClientSide(marker.ID);
}

private void InitializeClientSide(string markerId)
{
    btnGInfoWindow.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("windowMe("+ markerId +");"));
}

private void ConfigureClientSide()
{
    string js = string.Format(@"function windowMe(markerId){{var marker = getGMapElementById(subgurim_GMap1,markerId);  marker.openInfoWindowHtml('Hello world!'); }}", GMap1.GMap_Id);

    GMap1.addCustomJavascript(js);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
private void InitializeServerSide()
    {
        GMap1.addInfoWindow(GetInfoWindow(new GLatLng(7.225261, 80.198994)));
    }

protected GInfoWindow GetInfoWindow(GLatLng loc)
    {
        GIcon icon = new GIcon();
        icon.image = "http://localhost:9477/icons/red.png";
        icon.shadow = "http://localhost:9477/icons/shadow.png";
        icon.iconSize = new GSize(50, 50);
        icon.shadowSize = new GSize(0, 0);
        icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(6, 18);
        icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(0, 0);
        GMarkerOptions mOpts = new GMarkerOptions();
        mOpts.icon = icon;
        GMarker marker = new GMarker(loc, mOpts);
        GInfoWindow infoWindow = new GInfoWindow(marker, "Line ID: <a href=\"http://google.com\" target=\"_blank\">sachinda</a>", GListener.Event.click);
        return infoWindow;
    }
```